# GKE, how to avoid DaemonSet being evicted by cluster autoscaler?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

This is my DaemonSet

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: nginx
      annotations:
        "cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/enable-ds-eviction": "false"
        "cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/safe-to-evict": "false"
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          protocol: TCP
```

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#how-can-i-enabledisable-eviction-for-a-specific-daemonset).

**cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/enable-ds-eviction: "false"** should prevent scaling down.

But GKE cluster autoscaler ignores this annotation.

Is there any way to prevent DaemonSet from being evicted by the cluster autoscaler?

Comment: Are you saying the DS is being evicted prior to other deployments on the node itself or are you saying that the entire node is being scaled down (which of course includes the DS)

Comment: Entire node is being scaled down. I hope not to scale down this node when this kind of DS exists.

Comment: A DaemonSet runs a pod on _every_ node, though; it seems like this would prevent the cluster autoscaler from scaling in at all.

Comment: What I want to do is I will remove this annotation when DaemonSet finishes its work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/enable-ds-eviction` annotation does not apply once a node is actually empty.  During the scale down process, while the autoscaler is evicting/rescheduling pods elsewhere, it will ignore daemonsets when `cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/enable-ds-eviction` is set to false.  Once the node is empty (i.e. no longer has any deployed pods), the node will then be removed (and the daemonset pod will be gracefully terminated).

Comment: It seems that I misunderstood this annotation. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: I thought about it. Whether it is true or false, this will scale down. What is the real use of this annotation?

Comment: It's to ensure that while a node has pods deployed that the  daemonset is not evicted.  For example, if the autoscaler determines it can move pods to other nodes, it won't evict the daemonset during the scale down process.  But once the node is empty, it will remove the node.